# New GPU Coil Whine

Tags: graphics-card, troubleshooting

I just upgraded my rig, and part of the upgrade was a RTX2070 Super XC Hybrid.
Under normal load it sounds fine. Doing benchmarking, it is fine.
However, loading any games that have decent GPU usage, or doing a 'stress test', produces a loud buzz/squeal from the GPU.
I attempted to use the manufacturer's software to reduce the clock, which made the noise 'thinner', but the main high-pitch squeal is still there.
Adjusting graphics to LOW is the only way to reduce the sound in game, but its still there.
I also attempted restricting FPS in-game. Reducing it to 25fps made no noticeable changes to the noise.

Posting on their community forum got me a standard response of "put glue on the noisy parts", "Burn it in overnight","reduce the voltage", "limit Frames", "Try different PSU", "try different Mobo", and lastly... play the lotto with RMA. (and, a note that "coil whines are harmless)

Unless i get a different solution by tonight, i'll probably try to burn it in overnight, and during work tomorrow using ATI tools.

I'm thinking of getting a diff PSU, but I just got all of this, and i have MORE than enough power available for all of this. If the burn-in doesn't work, i'll probably try getting a new PSU.... but overall, it just feels like a unlucky pull.

Does anyone have experiences with this, and have any ideas for how to rectify the situation?

Comment: RMA is the 100% free solution except for time.

Comment: I did a burn-in from 10pm til 4:30pm the next day... noise was still there.

I'm getting a new PSU, and a new case with better acoustics. If the PSU fixes it, thats good. if not, i'll see how loud it is in the new case.

If the noise is still really bad, i've already contacted their support for an RMA.
Didn't WANT to get new case and PSU, but it doesn't hurt.